# MDX Count on Dimensions

Tags: count, dimension

i´m an MDX starter and have created following query: I want to get the count of POS Number for each region.

WITH

SET [Test_Count] as ([Shipped].[POS Number].[POS Number],[Geography].[Geography].[Region].members)

Member [Measures].[Count2] as Count(existing [Test_Count])

select

Count2

on columns,

[Geography].[Geography].[Region].members

on rows

from

[TestCube]

and this is the result for each region:

Region1: 481572
Region2: 481572
Region3: 481572
Region4: 481572

What i´m doing wrong? Can someone please help me?